# Matplotlib figures not moving with frames

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib, tkinter, latex

I can post the whole GUI and files necessary to run it, if needed. I'm trying to embed math equations in frames that correspond to several different models. All of these frames are loaded at the start of the application. This is a WIP and thus the equations that are to be drawn are hard coded using ifs, they will be later supplied by an external config file (which I've already done for the rest of the GUI).

I am navigating through these frames by assigning a value to 'frame' variable and then using frame.tkraise() to raise selected variable on top of each other frame, but the math equations are not moving with the frames - the canvas with the equations stays on top of all other things in the main frame. This results in equations loaded with the last model being always on top, despite my moving the frames.

How do I rephrase the code so that the equations follow the frames they are part of? I've tried asking at python@Freenode, searching through Google (~50 pages of different queries) and through documentation (which unfortunately is very scarce for Tkinter).

Here's the excerpt of the code:

```
class Model(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller, model_name):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Model: %s" % (model_name))
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        #self.f = mplfig.Figure(figsize=(3.59,3.35))

        print model_name

        if model_name == 'LotkaVolterra':
            self.eq1 = mplfig.Figure(figsize=(3.59,3.35))
            #self.eq1 = self.f#.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], axisbg='white')
            self.eq1.text(0.05, 0.875, r'$\frac{d[X]}{dt}=k_{1}[X]-k_{2}[X][Y]$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq1.text(0.05, 0.750, r'$\frac{d[Y]}{dt}=-k_{3}[Y]+k_{4}[X][Y]$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq1.text(0.05, 0.625, r'$A+X\rightarrow 2X \;(k_{1})$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq1.text(0.05, 0.500, r'$X+Y\rightarrow 2Y \;(k_{2} \; and \; k_{4})$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq1.text(0.05, 0.375, r'$Y\rightarrow B \;(k_{3})$', fontsize=14)
            #self.eq1.set_xticklabels([])
            #self.eq1.set_yticklabels([])
            #self.eq1.set_xticks([])
            #self.eq1.set_yticks([])
            self.canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.eq1, master=parent)
            #self.canvas.show()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1)

        elif model_name == 'Brusselator':
            self.eq2 = mplfig.Figure(figsize=(3.59,3.35))
            #self.eq2 = self.f#.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], axisbg='white')
            self.eq2.text(0.05, 0.875, r'$\frac{d[X]}{dt}=k_{1}[A]-k_{2}[B][X]+k_{3}[X]^{2}[Y]-k_{4}[X]$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq2.text(0.05, 0.750, r'$\frac{d[Y]}{dt}=k_{2}[B][X]-k_{3}[X]^{2}[Y]$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq2.text(0.05, 0.625, r'$A\rightarrow X \;(k_{1})$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq2.text(0.05, 0.500, r'$B+X\rightarrow Y+D \;(k_{2})$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq2.text(0.05, 0.375, r'$2X+Y\rightarrow 3X \;(k_{3})$', fontsize=14)
            self.eq2.text(0.05, 0.250, r'$X\rightarrow E \;(k_{4})$', fontsize=14)
            #self.eq2.set_xticklabels([])
            #self.eq2.set_yticklabels([])
            #self.eq2.set_xticks([])
            #self.eq2.set_yticks([])
            self.canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.eq2, master=parent)
            #self.canvas.show()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1)

        elif model_name == 'Oregonator':
            self.eq3 = mplfig.Figure(figsize=(3.59,3.35))
            #self.eq3 = self.f#.add_axes([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0], axisbg='white')
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.875, r'$\frac{d[X]}{dt}=k_{1}[A][Y]-k_{2}[X][Y]+k_{3}[A][X]-2k_{4}[X]^{2}$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.750, r'$\frac{d[Y]}{dt}=-k_{1}[B][X]-k_{2}[X][Y]+0.5fk_{5}[B][Z]$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.625, r'$\frac{d[Y]}{dt}=2k_{3}[A][X]-k_{5}[B][Z]$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.500, r'$A+Y\rightarrow X+P \;(k_{1})$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.400, r'$X+Y\rightarrow 2P \;(k_{2})$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.300, r'$A+X\rightarrow 2X+2Z \;(k_{3})$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.200, r'$2X\rightarrow A+P \;(k_{4})$', fontsize=13)
            self.eq3.text(0.05, 0.100, r'$B+Z\rightarrow fY \;(k_{5})$', fontsize=13)
            #self.eq3.set_xticklabels([])
            #self.eq3.set_yticklabels([])
            #self.eq3.set_xticks([])
            #self.eq3.set_yticks([])
            self.canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.eq3, master=parent)
            #self.canvas.show()
            self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1)

        #self.canvas = tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f, master=parent)
        #self.canvas.show()
        #self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1)
        self.grid()
```

As you can see, an instance of Model class will have a Label with appropriate model name (labels move correctly) and set of LaTeX equations and chemical reactions (these don't move correctly). How do I rephrase this? I've tried various approaches to no avail. Using labels would obviously solve the navigation problem, but tk.Label doesn't understand LaTeX. Neither does tk.Canvas. Only MatPlotLib Tkinter backend understands LaTeX.

I want the LaTeX equations to follow tk.Labels when frames are moved upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the canvas you do `master=parent`. Have you tried setting `master` to `self`?

Comment: Wow... Thanks! Is there a way to add relief=SUNKEN to the canvas?

Comment: I'm getting a black frame around the last canvas (navigation works now, thanks!). Also, when I exit the application using self.quit() and self.destroy() on the mainframe window I get this: "Fatal Python error: PyEval_RestoreThread: NULL tstate". Should I present the whole code so you can take a look?

Comment: @user2126752: I've never used matplotlib, so I probably wouldn't be able to help you with the fatal error you're seeing, as that looks to be coming from matplotlib.

Comment: Is there a better way to embed the equations? I would prefer to refrain from pictures and keep them as TeX.

Comment: @user2126752: I have no idea. I've never needed to do that.